# Can’t run Craft CMS :(

Tags: install

I'm getting the following message, when I try to access craft admin.

I have both the zip and unzip installed. Not sure why I'm getting this error.

---

MESSAGE:

Can’t run Craft CMS :(

Your server doesn’t meet the following requirements to run Craft CMS:

The zip extension is required for zip and unzip operations.
Please talk to your host/IT department about upgrading your server.

Answer (score 1):

The error shows up because Craft can’t find the zip php extension.

Try to install it by running `pecl install zip` in your terminal.